# transitive subgroup of an action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Suppose that we have a group G acting transitively on the set X, is there a smallest subgroup H of G, such that H acts transitively on X?

I was thinking if it's possible to construct H, such that for any x and y in X, there is a unique h  in H that maps from x to y.

Comment: This uniqueness you mention seems like a problem. If you take $x \in X$ and the stabilizer $G_x$, you want to choose one representative for each equivalence class $hG_x$ to build your $H \subset G$. However, it might not be possible to choose it in a way that $H$ is a group.

Comment: Does "smallest" mean $H$ is a subgroup of all transitive subgroups of $G$?  Or that $H$ doesn't properly contain any transitive subgroups of $G$?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, so if M is another transitive subgroup, and H is in M, then H = M. (So H  doesn't properly contain any transitive subgroups of G? )

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily a unique smallest transitive subgroup. A simple example of that is$H$ dihedral of order $8$ acting on $4$ points, for which there are two (necessarily minimal) transitive subgroups of order $4$, and they are both regular, so they both have the uniqueness property you mentioned.

As for whether there exists some minimal transitive subgroup, clearly yes for finite $X$, but probably not in general.

There are finite examples with no regular subgroups. One such example is $A_4$ acting on $6$ points. It is well-known that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: I think an example that has no minimal transitive subgroup would be $C_2\wr \mathbb Z$, acting on the cosets of $\mathbb Z$. If $N$ denotes the $(C_2)^\infty$ base group, then that is a regular normal subgroup, and $N.(n\mathbb Z)$ should be a collection of transitive subgroups with no minimal element.

Comment: Thank you professor, may I ask how we can prove that such minimal transitive subgroup exist for finite set?

Comment: The set of all transitive subgroups is finite, hence has a smallest member?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I was wondering if it is possible to construct a subset (not necessary a subgroup) $H$ such that $|H| = |X|$, and for any $x$, $y$ in $X$, there is a unique $h$ in $H$ that maps from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: You shouldn't keep changing the question. You should accept the answer for this one and ask a new question about the existence of a regular subset.

Answer (score 0):

Take the additive $\mathbb{Z}$, acting naturally on $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0,1\}$.

Take any odd number $n$.

Then, $n\mathbb{Z}$ acts transitively over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. This is a descending chain of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting transitively on $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Their intersection is $\{0\}$, which is not transitive.

If $n$ is even, then $n\mathbb{Z}$ does not act transitively.

So, there is no minimal subgroup for this action.

Comment: This example is not faithful. I mean, anyone can just take $G\times H$ and let $H$ act trivially and have any property you want. See my comment under Derek's answer for a faithful example.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: Where did you get this information that the example has to be faithful??? If you want to suggest a different example, you can simply write your own answer!!! I like mine, because it is simple and makes people wonder how the question can be improved... for example, by imposing that the action has to be faithful.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: and if $H$ acts trivially, $G \times \{1\}$ would act transitively as well. So, your commend does not make anything easier.

Comment: I didn't make my own answer because Derek's was good enough. Together with my comment giving a faithful example where there is no minimum, the question was completely answered. I don't know why you answered as well. But whatever.

Comment: (You are of course right that $G\times H$ has the transitive subgroup $G\times 1$. I don't know what I was saying about that.)