# A regular subset of a transitive group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Given a group $G$ acts transitively on a finite set $X$, we know that it is not necessarily true that it has a transitive subgroup of order $|X| $([transitive subgroup of an action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267509/transitive-subgroup-of-an-action)). However, I was wondering if $G$ has a subset $S$, with order $|X|$, such that for all $x$, $y$ in $X$, there is a unique element of $S$ that maps from $x$ to $y$?

Comment: I wouldn’t use $H$ for a subset of a group which is not a subgroup. Just bound to be confusion. $S$ is fine.

Comment: I have no idea why this question is getting downvotes and  votes to close. I would guess that the answer is no, but it would be interesting to see an example.

Comment: The $A_4$ example acting on six points does not have such a subset.

Comment: On the other hand, they can clearly exist, for example the set

$\{(1,2)(3,4)(5,6),\\(1,3)(2,6)(4,5),\\(1,4)(2,5)(3,6),\\(1,5)(2,3)(4,6),\\(1,6)(2,4)(3,5),1\}$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Is there some clever way of showing that $A_4$ has no such subset, or is it just a brute force check?

Comment: @DerekHolt Brute force I'm afraid. I stared at the set of elements generated by Magma and saw that even (with that representation) you couldn't do $1\mapsto 2$ and $1\mapsto 3$ without a clash. You can maybe start with noting that there are exactly two elements that map any point to any other one, but then I thought it was just easier to look.

Comment: Is the action of $A_4$ on a six element set just the obvious action on $2$-sets of $\{1,2,3,4\}?$ @DavidA.Craven

Comment: @ThomasAndrews All transitive actions on six points are isomorphic, because $A_4$ has only one subgroup of order $2$ up to conjugacy.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven okay, wrote an answer using your example. Most of it is describing the action - the proof is easy.

Comment: If you think of it as the action on $2$-subsets, we already get a contradiction trying to find a subset that includes only one map, for each $|A|=2,$ that send $A\mapsto A$ and $A\mapsto [4]\setminus A$ for each $A.$

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on a comment above by David A. Craven.

We will show a counter-example.

The elements of $A_4$ are:

$$e,\\(123),(132),\\(124),(142),\\(134),(143),\\(234),(243),\\(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23).$$

They act on $X,$ the $2$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\},$ inherited by their permutations. The six $2$-subsets are:

$$12,13,14,23,24,34$$

Any transitive subset of $A_4$ must contain one of the elements of order $2,$ since we need $12\mapsto 34.$ Only $(13)(24)$ or $(14)(23)$ do that, and we can only have one of them if we require uniqueness.

But if our transitive subset has the uniqueness property, then $e$ cannot be in the transitive subset, since $13$ is fixed by $(13)(24)$ and $14$ is fixed by $(14)(23).$

But the elements of order $3$ do not fix any of the elements of $X.$ So we need each of the elements of order $2$ to have  permutations in our transitive set which send $x\mapsto x$ for each $x\in X.$

But we already saw that we can’t have two elements of order $2$ if we require uniqueness.

So there is no such set.